# Deprecation warning for a struct element - I only want warnings when that element is referenced

Tags: c++, deprecation-warning

Here's my use case:

```
#ifndef MY_OPTIONS_H
#define MY_OPTIONS_H

#define DEPRECATED __attribute__((deprecated))

struct MyOptions {
    int fee;
    int fie;
    int foe;
    DEPRECATED int foo;
};

#endif
```

My main program:

```
#include <optional>

#include "my_options.hpp"

static MyOptions
genOptions()
{
    MyOptions rval;
    rval.fee = 1;
    rval.fie = 2;
    rval.foe = 3;
    return rval;     // <= error is here, implicit copy constructor
}

int
main()
{
    MyOptions options = genOptions();

    return 0;
}
```

And the errors it generates:

```
$ c++ -Wall -o tester tester.cpp
In file included from tester.cpp:3:
./my_options.hpp:6:8: warning: 'foo' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
struct MyOptions {
       ^
tester.cpp:12:12: note: in implicit copy constructor for 'MyOptions' first required here
    return rval;
           ^
./my_options.hpp:10:5: note: 'foo' has been explicitly marked deprecated here
    DEPRECATED int foo;
    ^
./my_options.hpp:4:35: note: expanded from macro 'DEPRECATED'
#define DEPRECATED __attribute__((deprecated))
                                  ^
tester.cpp:18:15: warning: unused variable 'options' [-Wunused-variable]
    MyOptions options = genOptions();
              ^
2 warnings generated.
```

Comment: Which compiler? As far as I can tell GCC (and Clang) already implement the attribute like that. (Since C++14 there is also a standardized attribute with the same effect: `[[deprecated]]`.)

Comment: clang for now. I'll need to get this to work with Microsoft C and gcc as well. Let me try a complete but small example.

Comment: @EdwardFalk cannot reproduce https://godbolt.org/z/o6o7KW19b

Comment: Ahh, the problem comes up in an implicit copy or move constructor. I've added the source to my test program to illustrate.

Comment: I *could* track down every implicit copy or move constructor of MyOptions and wrap them with the appropriate `#ifdef`s to suppress the warning. There are rather a lot of them.

Comment: Or I could write explicit move & copy constructors, and delete them later when the deprecated members are finally removed.

Comment: It seems that only Clang considers the implicit functions a "use" of the member for the purpose of the deprecation attribute. The standard recommends warning "_in case the program refers to a name or entity other than to declare it_". I guess the "_entity_" part may leave room to include the implicit use. I can see both approaches making sense, but unfortunately I don't think there is a good solution in general. Maybe it is possible to declare and default the special member functions and suppress the warning on their declarations, but that would (since C++20) make the class non-aggregate.

Comment: A similar issue was reported for aggregate initialization, where the member is also not named explicitly: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/44515